# How to interpret the method with set type in C++

Tags: c++, set

I have work on C++ with set method data type. Method is

```
set < string, cmp > genPerm ( const string& );
```

here cmp is a class

I don't know how to interpret these type of methods, from 4 hours I have search and understand the set but each time problem occurs and task is not solved. Any one help me guide me about

Comment: Perhaps all you need is [a good reference for `std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)? Or perhaps [a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: You could add some info about *what* part you don't understand. I see `genPerm` as a function taking a `string` parameter and returning a `set`. Much like  `int f(int x);`.

Answer (score 2):

That is a function declaration of type `std::set<std::string, cmp>` accepting one `std::string` parameter by reference to const. The [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) container is also a type. So your function is of that type. The first parameter in `<std::string, cmp>` template determines the type of elements stored in a set which is a `std::string`. Set is a sorted container of unique elements. The second parameter in the set template is a [key comparison function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) that determines how the elements are sorted. In your case the custom sorting is provided by your `cmp` class which probably overloads the `()` operator and is actually a functor. The return type of the function is:

```
std::set<std::string, cmp, std::allocator<std::string>>
```

which is equivalent to:

```
std::set<std::string, cmp>
```

If you didn't have the custom comparator `cmp` the return type would probably be:

```
std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>
```

which is actually:

```
std::set<std::string>
```

for short.

Comment: what is the return type of this method?